# how to display radio buttons with ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat, selectoneradio

I have some troubles displaying some data on a JSF page.
It deals with a pizza sql-search programm I have written. The java program itself works fine but the output makes some problem.

All pizzas are stored in an ArrayList of instances, like List< PizzaObject>. The class PizzaObject contains other instances like 'Pizza', 'Topping', 'Size'. So it is a nested list of different classes holding variable data.

For my output I make use of the ui:repeat method. There is no problem displaying the pizza and their attributes. But when it comes to display their sizes nested in a ui-repeat loop as SelectOneRadio-buttons, there is no output.

All pizzas are stored in an ArrayList, looking like this:

```
List<PizzaObject> results = new ArrayList<PizzaObject>();
```

The PizzaObject class looks like this:

```
public static class PizzaObject {
   Pizza pizza;
   List<Size> sizeList;
   List<Topping> toppingList;

   public PizzaObject(Pizza pizza, List<Size> sizeList, List<Topping> toppingList) {
      this.pizza = pizza;
      this.sizeList = sizeList;
      this.toppingList = toppingList;
   }

   // getter and setter
}
```

The classes Pizza, Topping and Size contain different attributes belonging to each Pizza object.
For example the Size class looks like this:

```
public static class Size {
   int sizeID;
   int diameter;

   public Size(int sizeID, int diameter) {
        this.sizeID = sizeID;
        this.diameter = diameter;
   }

   // getter and setter
}
```

In my JSF output page I now want to display each pizza and each of their sizes and toppings. But since they don't have the same sizes I need to iterate the list sizeList and this is where the error occurs.

```
<ui:repeat var="results" value="#{pizzaSearchBean.results}">
   <p>#{results.pizza.name}</p>
   <p>sizes: </p>
   <h:selectOneRadio id="pizzasize" value="#{pizzaSearchBean.pizzasize}">
      <ui:repeat var="sizes" value="#{results.sizeList}">
         <f:selectItem id="size" itemLabel="#{sizes.diameter}" itemValue="#{sizes.sizeID}"/>
      </ui:repeat>
   </h:selectOneRadio>
</ui:repeat>
```

I don't know why there is no output of radio boxes but I don't think that I have implemented it incorrectly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where did you see/learn that you could use `<ui:repeat><f:selectItem>`? Then I can rectify that wrong source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `[<f:selectitems>][1]`, this is intended to render multiple component based on a collection. For instance, you could replace your `<ui:repeat>` with

```
<f:selectItems value="#{results.sizeList}" var="size"
               itemLabel="#{size.diameter}" itemValue="#{size.sizeId}" />
```